# Taking weighted average up to a particular index without using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to see what kind of price move to expect when a large order goes through the orderbook. I have orderbook snapshot data that looks like:

```
                         bid_price  bid_size  ask_price ask_size    level bid_size_cumsum   ask_size_cumsum
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6717.49 0.735502    6717.50 56.117221   0   0.735502    56.117221
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6717.22 0.300000    6717.56 0.018600    1   1.035502    56.135821
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6717.01 1.000000    6717.94 0.001000    2   2.035502    56.136821
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6717.00 2.500000    6718.30 0.001000    3   4.535502    56.137821
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6716.78 0.001000    6718.46 0.003000    4   4.536502    56.140821
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6716.25 0.617698    6718.95 2.225920    5   5.154200    58.366741
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6716.19 0.046394    6719.00 6.900000    6   5.200593    65.266741
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6715.00 0.001000    6719.20 0.001000    7   5.201593    65.267741
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6712.94 2.895080    6719.26 0.001000    8   8.096673    65.268741
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6710.98 1.033114    6719.96 0.001000    9   9.129787    65.269741
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6710.85 1.870000    6720.00 8.316950    10  10.999787   73.586691
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6710.78 0.306467    6720.01 0.001000    11  11.306254   73.587691
2018-08-27 14:25:30+00:00   6710.62 0.900000    6720.02 2.848228    12  12.206254   76.435919
```

The levels are orderbook levels so level 0 would be top of the book.
Say if I want to sell a qty of 10 through the bids, I can see from bid_size_cumsum that I will get my 10 when it reaches a level of 10. Now I want to calculate the average bid_price until level 10. It would be a weighted average of bid_price*bid_size. Is there a way to calculate (bid_price*bid_size)/total_size until Level 10 without using a For loop?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data stored in `df`. If the data is numeric, you can just apply operations as mult. / add and other to your data:

```
ten_rows = df[:10]  # Slice first ten values from your data frame
result = ten_rows['bid_price'] * ten_rows['bid_size'] / ten_rows['bid_size_cumsum']
```

result is target weighted average. 
P.S. check dtype of your data if you will get some `TypeError`: `df.dtypes`. It should be int/float type if you plan to use mathematical operators.